# Counting vertices of a tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I was told a tree has non-leaf vertices with degrees $5,5,5,8,10$, and I was told to calculate how many total vertices there are.

I thought to draw the tree in three levels - top one is a choice of a root, middle one is other non-leaf vertices and remaining leaves, and lowest one is the remaining leaves.

Then we assign "corrected degrees" telling us how many vertices are below each vertex. This leaves the root fixed and lowers all other degrees by $1$. So if we start with non-leaf vertices $v_1,\dots ,v_n$, the result should be $(\sum_{i=1}^n\deg v_i)-(n-1)$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that there are $n$ leaves. Then the sum of the degrees of the vertices is $33+n$, and there are $n+5$ vertices altogether. Use the handshaking lemma and the fact that a tree has one more vertex than it has edges to solve for $n$.

Comment: I haven't learned the handshaking lemma yet. Is my attempt wrong?

Comment: @combinarcotics: I’m afraid so, because there’s no guarantee that all of the other interior vertices are adjacent to the root: you might need more levels. The handshaking lemma is easy: it just says that the sum of the degrees of the vertices in any graph is twice the number of edges. This is because each edge has two ends, so when you add the degrees of the vertices, you’re counting each edge twice.

Comment: That problem occurred to me but I got confused since it seemed I can draw tree with given non-leaf degrees to have just three levels - pick a root, connect all interior vertices to it, and connect to everything however many leaves are needed. What am I missing here?

Comment: @combinarcotics: You’re missing the fact that that isn’t the *only* possibility. You need to make sure that you give an argument that covers every possible tree with the specified degrees.

Comment: By that do you mean some trees can be drawn with different numbers of levels, or that not all trees may be drawn this way? I'm guessing it's the latter?

Comment: @combinarcotics: I mean that a tree with the specified degrees may have as few as $3$ and as many as $6$ levels.

Comment: Ahh, I think binary trees with many vertices cannot be drawn with just three levels. I see now. I think my wrong calculation still yields a correct answer in this case. Do you agree? I took the degree ten vertex as a root..

Comment: @combinarcotics: And in fact it will yield the correct answer in every case, because the number of leaves is completely determined by the information given no matter how the tree is put together. But you can’t assume this without proof, and the argument that I suggested provides that proof by deriving the number of leaves without making any assumption about the number of levels.

Comment: Okay so just to be sure - my final answer is correct, but my derivation is wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: @combinarcotics: The final answer is off by $1$, because what you’ve actually counted is the *edges*, not the vertices. Any tree with interior vertices with these degrees must have $29$ edges, the number that you calculated, and therefore will have $30$ vertices.

Comment: Really clear now. Thank you!

Comment: @combinarcotics: You’re welcome!